# Several screens "overlapping" pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I started today to program a game with pygame. In the background is a kind of grid on which you will play in the future. But I noticed that with a while loop to update the screen, the grid is redrawn every time and that's a waste of resources, because nothing changes there anyway. Now I thought about not updating the grid-screen in the background and creating a new screen to play on, which will be updated. But then I encountered a problem: When pygame starts a new screen, the last one closes.
So is it smart to have the game board redrawn every time or is there another method where you can leave an item in the background without updating it? Thank you very much for any help. Code and (wrong) approaches follow.

main.py

```
import field, game
import ctypes


# Variables
def main():
    width, height = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
    width_scale, height_scale = 5 / 10, 9 / 10
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    background_color = (214, 237, 255)
    refresh_rate = 60
    field_size = [10, 18]

    screen = pg.display.set_mode([int(width * width_scale), int(height * height_scale)], pg.NOFRAME)

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                pass
        screen.fill(background_color)
        box_size = field.draw_boxes(screen.get_width(), screen.get_height(), field_size, screen)
        field.draw_next_hand()
        pg.display.flip()

        game.main(width, height, box_size, field_size)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

field.py

```
import pygame as pg


def draw_boxes(w, h, size, screen):
    global start_x, box_size, g_screen, grey, s
    g_screen = screen
    s = size
    box_size = int(w / 2 / (size[0]+1))
    start_x = int(w / 2 - size[0] / 2 * box_size)
    grey = (122, 122, 122)


    for column in range(0, size[0], 1):
        for row in range(0, size[1], 1):
            pg.draw.rect(screen, grey, [start_x + column * box_size, box_size + row * box_size, box_size, box_size], width= 1)

    return box_size

def draw_next_hand():
    global box_size, start_x, g_screen, grey
    next_hand_size = 4
    next_hand_distance = 1

    for column in range(0, next_hand_size, 1):
        for row in range(0, next_hand_size, 1):
            pg.draw.rect(g_screen, grey, [start_x - 2*box_size*next_hand_distance - column * box_size, box_size + row * box_size, box_size, box_size], width=1)
            pg.draw.rect(g_screen, grey, [start_x + box_size*s[0] + box_size * next_hand_distance + column * box_size, box_size + row * box_size, box_size, box_size], width=1)
```

game.py

```
import pygame as pg
from main import main

def main(width, height, box_size, f_size):

    # Variables
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    grey = (122, 122, 122)
    refresh_rate = 60


    g_screen = pg.display.set_mode([int(f_size[0] * box_size), int(f_size[1] * box_size)], pg.NOFRAME)
    while True:
        g_screen.fill(white)
        pg.display.flip()
        pg.time.delay(refresh_rate)
```

Before I added the new screen I had "pg.time.delay(refresh_rate)" instead of "game.main()", which caused the background to be constantly redrawn, so I tried to draw another screen over it, which of course didn't work^^

I've already found some entries on stack overflow, but they didn't fit my problem, because it was suggested to change the screen with for example main = False and game = True, but this wouldn't prevent the board from being redrawn

Comment: It is common to redraw the scene in every frame. This may seem useless and a waste of resources in a simple game, but it makes no difference in modern games with a dynamic scene in which something changes in almost every frame. Don't wast your time.

Comment: A simple approach would be to update the display only if at least 1 event was handled in a frame.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to improve the performance concerning the background image.

- **Draw once** - You can store the background image in a surface object so it only needs to be generated once. Pygame will retain the screen when hidden or minimized.
- **Only redraw the updated section** - Set a clipping rectangle on the screen so only certain pixels get refreshed when the background is redrawn
- **Only redraw when needed** - The game loop is required, but you can conditionally re-render the background
- **Draw efficiently** - Slow down the game loop using the `pygame.time.Clock().tick()` method

Here's a short program that illustrates these points. It just shows the current date\time on a background of circles.

```
import pygame as pg
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
from random import randint

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def rnd(rg): # save some typing
   return randint(0,rg)

font_name = pg.font.match_font('arial')

def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y): # draw text on screen in rect
    font = pg.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, (rnd(255),rnd(255),rnd(255)))
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

def make_bg():  # create background image
   surf_bg = pg.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
   surf_bg.fill((0,0,0)) # start with black
   for i in range(500):  # 500 circles
      pg.draw.circle(surf_bg,(rnd(255),rnd(255),rnd(255)), (rnd(WIDTH),rnd(HEIGHT)), 15+rnd(50))
   return surf_bg

surf_bg = make_bg()  # generate circles once, store surface object

#initial background
screen.blit(surf_bg, screen.get_rect()) # draw background, only needed once in Windows
screen.set_clip((10, HEIGHT/2 - 20, WIDTH-10, HEIGHT/2 + 20)) # set active region on screen

lasttick = pg.time.get_ticks() # milliseconds since init

while True:
   pg.time.Clock().tick(5)  # run loop 5 times per second
   pg.event.get()  # required in Windows for OS events
   if pg.key.get_pressed()[pg.K_SPACE]: quit()  # press space to quit
   if (pg.time.get_ticks() - lasttick < 1000): continue # only redraw time each second
   lasttick = pg.time.get_ticks()  
   
   screen.blit(surf_bg, screen.get_rect())  # background, update clip region only
   draw_text(screen, str(dt.now()), 30, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 - 10) # draw time
   pg.display.flip() # swap screen buffer
```